# arithmetic value using DateTime and TimeSpan net core 2.0 and EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have DateTime variables

```
 private readonly TimeSpan thirtydays = new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0);
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
```

and TimeSpan used to calculate date in the future

```
process.DueDate = DateTime.Now + thirtydays;
```

Due date can be changed during the process life. I would like to list all processes where DueDate was changed.

.Where(d => d.DueDate != (d.RegistrationDate + thirtydays))

but I get an error

```
InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a TimeSpan to a DateTime.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__108_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `DateTime.Now.Add(thirtydays)`.EntityFramework (and Linq to database) generally works on expressions evaluating methods called and translate it

Comment: Doesn't work for me, nor Add, nor AddDays. Can't translate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
.Where(d => d.DueDate != d.RegistrationDate.AddDays(30))
```

In Entity Framework core this is translated into the SQL `DATEADD` function.